# Get RSS Memory usage from entire OS on command line

Tags: command-line, memory

I need to get the entire count of RAM being used on a command line. I can get individual process RSS usage using

```
ps -o rss= -p #{pid}
```

How do I get **all** the memory usage for the entire system on the command line?

Comment: A vote up from SO

Comment: To sum up all RSS from `ps` You can type:
 `ps ax -o rss= | awk '{s+=$1}END{print s}'`

Comment: Thanks, though i think this may be missing some. When I run that and convert to GB https://www.google.com/search?q=4189760+kb+to+gb&oq=4189760+kb+to+gb&aqs=chrome..69i57j0.8910j0j1&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=91&ie=UTF-8#q=4327472+kb+to+gb I get 4.127 GB though activity monitor shows 6.28 GB used